# Condensing the following code, preferably using a dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension, dict-comprehension

Is it possible (and, more importantly, practical) to write the following code as a dict comprehension?

I am creating a dictionary here and then checking for "blank" values (represented by a '-') and replacing it with another string value.

```
test_dict = dict(zip(list_one,list_two))
for k,v in test_dict.items():
    if v == '-':
        test_dict[k] = 'missing'
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not do the replacement when you are creating the dictionary?

```
test_dict = dict(zip(list_one, 
                     ('missing' if x == '-' else x for x in list_two)))
```

Or, if you have an existing dictionary you can create a **new** one using:

```
{k: 'missing' if v == '-' else v for k, v in d.items()}
```

If you wish to alter the **existing** dictionary in-place then really there is nothing wrong with the existing code. You could use a list comprehension such as:

```
[d.__setitem__(k, 'missing') for k, v in d.items() if v == '-']
```

but that is rather ugly.

Comment: it is not just ugly, there you are playing with mutability in a comprehension, building a completly useless list in memory which can be eventually  huge.

Comment: @DanielSanchez Clearly ... as I said, ugly.  (size isn't really an issue, this could be done with an equally ugly `any(...)` wrapped around it to avoid that)

Comment: Thanks so much @donkopotamus I like the first suggestion.